# Is there a way to set the symlink attribute for a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a directory that I moved from a Linux file system to an NTFS file system and broke all of the symlinks. Moving them back didn't fix the problem because all the symlinks are now very small files without the attributes that made them links. Lesson learned. Is there a way to reset the symlink attribute and convert these files back, or do I just need to write a script to find these files and batch recreate the links?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is look at those small files. Symbolic links are simply files with a special mode whose contents are the path they are linked to. I don't know how the file system was moved to/from NTFS, but it's possible these small files still contain the contents of the link.

With that in mind, it might be possible to re-create them with a script.

Comment: The content is still there, just not the flag that makes it a link. I actually already fixed my problem by reinstalling the programs, but the problem still exists for the next person.